# Bootstrap dropdown won't close on choosing an option

Tags: javascript, css

I have a dropdown list that has a nice select using bootstrap 3.4.1.
The issue that i have is that: the drop down remain open after select and never close unless i click outside the list.

HTML code:

```
<div id="countrysd" class="row option-box">
    <div class="option-box-header">
        <h3 style="color:#164680">Number <span style="color:#C32952">of Users</span> </h3>
        <p>Select the users country and move the range slider to set how many users </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <input type="hidden" id="option100Title" name="option100Title" value="Select" />
        <input type="hidden" id="option100Price" name="option100Price" value="0" />
        <select id="countryList" class="wide price-list" name="countryList" onchange="showChange()">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="egypt">Egypt User</option>
            <option value="uae">UAE User</option>
            <option value="usa">USA User</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript code that casuing the issue

```
!function(e){e.fn.niceSelect=function(t){function s(t){t.after(e("<div></div>").addClass("nice-select").addClass(t.attr("class")||"").addClass(t.attr("disabled")?"disabled":"").attr("tabindex",t.attr("disabled")?null:"0").html('<span class="current"></span><ul class="list"></ul>'));var s=t.next(),n=t.find("option"),i=t.find("option:selected");s.find(".current").html(i.data("display")||i.text()),n.each(function(t){var n=e(this),i=n.data("display");s.find("ul").append(e("<li></li>").attr("data-value",n.val()).attr("data-display",i||null).addClass("option"+(n.is(":selected")?" selected":"")+(n.is(":disabled")?" disabled":"")).html(n.text()))})}if("string"==typeof t)return"update"==t?this.each(function(){var t=e(this),n=e(this).next(".nice-select"),i=n.hasClass("open");n.length&&(n.remove(),s(t),i&&t.next().trigger("click"))}):"destroy"==t?(this.each(function(){var t=e(this),s=e(this).next(".nice-select");s.length&&(s.remove(),t.css("display",""))}),0==e(".nice-select").length&&e(document).off(".nice_select")):console.log('Method "'+t+'" does not exist.'),this;this.hide(),this.each(function(){var t=e(this);t.next().hasClass("nice-select")||s(t)}),e(document).off(".nice_select"),e(document).on("click.nice_select",".nice-select",function(t){var s=e(this);e(".nice-select").not(s).removeClass("open"),s.toggleClass("open"),s.hasClass("open")?(s.find(".option"),s.find(".focus").removeClass("focus"),s.find(".selected").addClass("focus")):s.focus()}),e(document).on("click.nice_select",function(t){0===e(t.target).closest(".nice-select").length&&e(".nice-select").removeClass("open").find(".option")}),e(document).on("click.nice_select",".nice-select .option:not(.disabled)",function(t){var s=e(this),n=s.closest(".nice-select");n.find(".selected").removeClass("selected"),s.addClass("selected");var i=s.data("display")||s.text();n.find(".current").text(i),n.prev("select").val(s.data("value")).trigger("change")}),e(document).on("keydown.nice_select",".nice-select",function(t){var s=e(this),n=e(s.find(".focus")||s.find(".list .option.selected"));if(32==t.keyCode||13==t.keyCode)return s.hasClass("open")?n.trigger("click"):s.trigger("click"),!1;if(40==t.keyCode){if(s.hasClass("open")){var i=n.nextAll(".option:not(.disabled)").first();i.length>0&&(s.find(".focus").removeClass("focus"),i.addClass("focus"))}else s.trigger("click");return!1}if(38==t.keyCode){if(s.hasClass("open")){var l=n.prevAll(".option:not(.disabled)").first();l.length>0&&(s.find(".focus").removeClass("focus"),l.addClass("focus"))}else s.trigger("click");return!1}if(27==t.keyCode)s.hasClass("open")&&s.trigger("click");else if(9==t.keyCode&&s.hasClass("open"))return!1});var n=document.createElement("a").style;return n.cssText="pointer-events:auto","auto"!==n.pointerEvents&&e("html").addClass("no-csspointerevents"),this}}(jQuery);
```

Please let me know if there is a solution for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was sorted when I removed `onchange="showChange()"`.